# Multiple swapping of rows and columns

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

```
m={{a, b, c, p}, {d, e, f, x}, {g, h, k, z}, {u, v, w, y}};
```

I want to swap 1st and 2nd rows by 4th and 3rd rows respectively. And then, swap 1st and 2nd columns by 4th and 3rd columns.

Comment: `Reverse[m, {1, 2}]`. Related: [(2546)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2546) and [(19726)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19726)

Comment: I don't think it is obvious that `Reverse` has second argument, but if you need to reverse something it is easy to face it in docs :) So my point is that it should be closed, but let's see what community says :)

Comment: @Kuba Unless it's a dup (I don't know), I think you could post it as an answer

Comment: Also related: [(3069)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069) and [(20228)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20228)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, encouraged by belisarius, here's the way.

If you know that `Reverse` exists you may use:

```
Reverse /@ Reverse @ m
```

then you could check the docs and realise that `Reverse` has 2nd argument:

```
Reverse[m, {1, 2}]
```

But if you don't but you are amazed by `Span`+`Part` you can end up with:

```
m[[;; , {4, 3, 2, 1}]][[{4, 3, 2, 1}]]
```

or even more `Span`:  :)

```
m[[;; , -1 ;; 1 ;; -1]][[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]
```

[Why is multidimensional Reverse slow?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37777/5478) - nice question where I've learned about `-1;;1;;-1`

Comment: Congratulations on joining the 20K club!  :-)  For some reason I still think of you as a "new" member but you have become a pillar of the community, and not by "reputation" alone.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for those kind words :) I do enjoy being here :), almost each day I can learn, or at least face, something new so thank you community of Mathematica.SE :)