# Replacement in a nested matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

We have a nested matrix

```
m1 = {{{1, 2, 2, I}, {1, 1, -2, 1}, {3, 2, 2, -I}}, {{3, 4, 4, I}, {1, 1, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 4, -1}}};
```

we must replace the first number of each sub_list with the third number and vise versa and and achieve to `m2` as:

```
m2 = {{{2, 2, 1, I}, {-2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3, -I}}, {{4, 4, 3, I}, {4, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 3, -1}}};
```

The shape of `m1` and `m2` are as below. We know that we can use of two loops with an `IF` condition but we don't think it is a good way. If Possible please let us know how can we obtain `m2`?

m1:

[image]

m2:

[image]

Comment: Closely related: [(3069)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/121), [(47017)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47017/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way:

```
m2 = Apply[{#3, #2, #, #4} &, m1, {2}]
```

or another:

```
m2 = m1;
m2[[;; , ;; , {3, 1}]] = m2[[;; , ;; , {1, 3}]];
m2
```

Comment: Can I use of MapAt instead of Apply[    ,{2}]?

Comment: @Ackaran `Apply` is shorter because with `Map` you have to refer to `#[[2]]` instead of `#2` etc. And you need `Map` not `MapAt`.

Comment: Damn, both of my favorite methods in one post.  Nothing left for me to write. :^)

Comment: The second way is so intelligent, I enjoyed it.

Comment: @Ackaran See the question I just linked in a comment below your post for more examples like this.

Comment: I favorite your address commented. That link contains more things to be understood and practiced.

Answer (score 3):

"Monster voodoo machine" method for those who want `MapAt`, do not want to bother with `Part` and like `Span`:

```
MapAt[Replace[{a_, b_, c_, d_} -> {c, b, a, d}], m1, {;; , ;;}]
```

Comment: You can use `Map[Replace[...], m1, {2}]` too.

Comment: @Kuba, I see it, but the OP asked for `MapAt`. I've made it just for fun :)))

Comment: BTW, this `Replace[m1, {a_, b_, c_, d_} -> {c, b, a, d}, {2}]` also does the job.

Answer (score 2):

```
 m = 
 {{{1, 2, 2, I}, {1, 1, -2, 1}, {3, 2, 2, -I}}, 
  {{3, 4, 4, I}, {1, 1, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 4, -1}}};

wanted = 
 {{{2, 2, 1, I}, {-2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3, -I}}, 
  {{4, 4, 3, I}, {4, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 3, -1}}};
```

Using `ReplaceAll`:

```
(m /. v_?VectorQ :> Reverse@RotateRight[v, 1]) === wanted

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = 
 {{{1, 2, 2, I}, {1, 1, -2, 1}, {3, 2, 2, -I}}, 
  {{3, 4, 4, I}, {1, 1, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 4, -1}}};

wanted = 
 {{{2, 2, 1, I}, {-2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3, -I}}, 
  {{4, 4, 3, I}, {4, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 3, -1}}};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
result = Map[SubsetMap[RotateRight, #, {1, 3}] &, m, {2}]
```

returns

```
 {{{2, 2, 1, I}, {-2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3, -I}}, 
  {{4, 4, 3, I}, {4, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 3, -1}}};

result == wanted
```

True