# Picking some elements of a matrix and generating another matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, filtering

If we have a nested matrix as:

```
start={
{{1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, -2, 1}, {3, 2, 2, -I}, {1, 2, 0, -I}}, 
{{3, 4, 4, 0}, {1, 1, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 4, -1}, {1, 1, 2, I}}
}
```

How can we choose the latest elements of sub_lists `3,1,-I,-I,0,1,-1,I` and create of them a matrix as

```
final={{3,1,-I,-I},{0,1,-1,I}}
```

Comment: Please focus on answers you've already received. E.g. [104564](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104564/5478).

Comment: I tried to use of those answer I used final= Apply[{#4} &, start, {2}]; unfortunately I think I could not deeply understand that. @Kuba, are there good references for list manipulation (however Mr.Wizard introduced a link but I want to be familiar with a more practical documentation (containing practical examples) about list manipulation)

Comment: @Arkaran, will you start to learn carefully from the answers that you receive?  `start[[;; , ;; , -1]]`

Comment: For example if I search `Map`(which is used by David G.Stork) in mathematica help I will see `Map[f, {a, b, c, d, e}]={f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d], f[e]}` I cannot understand what are `a, b, c, ..` are they sub_lists or each elements in sub_lists!!! Just in examples we can see what happen in list manipulation.

Comment: @garej, thanks for your comment,, i can imagine, I must concentrate on answers. and try to learn their keys.

Comment: @Ackaran, you may experiment with examples, i.e. make your own to try. Compare: `Map[Style[f, Red], Thread[List[{a, b, c, d, e}, {a, b, c, d, e}]]]` and `Map[Style[f, Red], Thread[List[{a, b, c, d, e}, {a, b, c, d, e}]], {-1}]`

Comment: @Ackaran take a look here too: [the most common pitfalls](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/5478). Once you become familiar with list manipulation, MMA will be a lot of fun.

Comment: @Ackaran, do not forget to check `Map[Last, start, {-2}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
Map[Last, start, {2}]
```